# Using Powershell how to Revert-to-Parent in handler mappings for an application in IIS

Tags: powershell, iis, handler, revert, mappings

I want to modify the IIS Web application Handler mappings to Revert to Parent.
I did this manually like below.

Open IIS , Site/Web application, Clicked Handler Mappings, in Actions Clicked "Revert to Parent".

I want to automate this using PowerShell.
Can someone help?

I have already tried below :-

1)
Clear-WebConfiguration -pspath 'IIS:/sites/Default Web Site/MyWebService' -filter 'system.webServer/handlers'

2)
Clear-WebConfiguration -Filter /System.WebServer/Handlers -PSPath 'IIS:/sites/Default Web Site/MyWebService' -force

3)
Set-WebConfiguration -Filter /System.WebServer/Handlers -Value @{Name='CGI-exe'; EntryType='Inherited'; AccessPolicy="Read, Script"} -PSPath "IIS:/sites/Default Web Site/MyWebService"

4)
Set-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/handlers/@AccessPolicy/add[@name='CGI-exe']" -Value "Read, Script" -PSPath "IIS:/sites/Default Web Site/MyWebService"

Set-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/handlers/add[@name='CGI-exe']/@requireAccess" -Value "Execute" -PSPath "IIS:/sites/Default Web Site/MyWebService"

But none suffices my need to "Revert to Parent"

Comment: Does anyone know about this?